# navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia() not working iOS 11 standalone apps

Tags: ios, webrtc, ios11

`navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()` is not working iOS 11 standalone apps. Does work in Safari 11 browser page.

Is this intentional? temporary?

Also, I can't get Safari 11 web inspector (MacOS Sierra 10.12.6) to even recognize any standalone web apps running on iPhone 7 with IOS11. It does recognize standalone apps pre IOS 11 iPhones. Also try{}catch{} reveals that `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()` is not valid call from standalone app in iPhone 7 running iOS 11.

Comment: I have same problem. The cam it seem be already but it appears black.

Comment: relates to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53483975/navigator-mediadevices-getusermedia-not-working-on-ios-12-safari

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/og6up9d4/show

Answer (score 3):

In iOS 11, `getUserMedia` is only supported in Safari, not in UIWebView, WKWebView, SFSafariViewController, or web apps added to the home screen:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/88052

Comment: Nothing in the link you provided says anything about no support for web apps which is considerable different from the hybrid native cases (UIWebView, WKWebView, SFSafariViewController). It does seem obvious from my tests but I knew that before posting. Do you have support for an official claim of nonsupport for PWA (which is still technically Safari)?