# Navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia not working on iOS 12 Safari

Tags: ios, iphone, webrtc, getusermedia, ios12

As of iOS 12, `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()` is returning an error in Safari.

To recreate this, open [iPhone Web Inspector](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html), then run this snippet in the console:

```
var constraints = { audio: true, video: { width: 1280, height: 720 } }; 

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
  .then(function() {
    console.log('getUserMedia completed successfully.');
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error.name + ": " + error.message);
  });
```

You'll see that this runs successfully in desktop browsers, and in iOS 11 Safari, but fails in iOS 12 Safari.

> NotAllowedError: The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.

Any idea why?

*note: This is happening prior to the user being asked if their camera can be accessed, ruling out the possibility of it being because the user denied permission.*

Comment: Severisth, if you open the fiddle with '/show' it works `https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/og6up9d4/show`

Comment: @ИскренСтаниславов link does not work on iOS 12.0, Safari 12 (I am using CrossBrowserTesting iPhone XS Max)

Answer (score 34):

Setting these three attributes before calling `getUserMedia` solved the problem for me:

```
    video.setAttribute('autoplay', '');
    video.setAttribute('muted', '');
    video.setAttribute('playsinline', '');
```

For some reason `video.setAttribute()` works but trying to assign the value directly to the video object for example `video.muted = ''` does not.

Also it appears that it's not necessary to call `video.play()`.

Simply setting the `video.srcObject` to the stream returned by `getUserMedia` worked for me.

This [medium post](https://medium.com/@leemartin/hello-webrtc-on-safari-11-e8bcb5335295) has a link to a working demo & source code.

Comment: This saved the day for me! I had to leave `await video.play()` in for desktop to keep working though (Firefox, haven't tried Chrome).

Comment: This recommendation is still valid in mid-May 2020. It's not necessary for iOS 13, only 11 and 12. Thanks.

Comment: This is still valid in Aug 2020. The `playsinline` seems the parameter that gets it working.

Comment: still valid August 2021, only necessary in iOS safari, not desktop safari

Comment: Also use
   video.play().catch((err) => function(){ alert(err)}) to catch and view the error.

Answer (score 26):

There are two possible reasons for immediate `NotAllowedError` at the moment:

### 1. getUserMedia requries https

Safari seems to require `https` for camera and mic access, both in iOS and OSX.

With [an https link](https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/r60bzmrs/), iOS Safari 12 works for me; [same link in http](http://jsfiddle.net/jib1/r60bzmrs/) gets `NotAllowedError`.

Chrome has the same requirement. This is consistent with the *direction* of the specification, which [recently](https://github.com/w3c/mediacapture-main/pull/550) has restricted `getUserMedia` to secure contexts. Browsers who have yet to update, still expose `navigator.mediaDevices` in http, but `getUserMedia` always rejects with `NotAllowedError`.

In the future, expect browsers to remove `mediaDevices` entirely in http, to comply with the spec.

### 2. getUserMedia requires feature policy in cross-origin iframes.

This appears new with Safari 12. In iframes, `getUserMedia`'s feature policy is off by default for cross-origin content.

[This works](https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/og6up9d4/) for me:

```
<iframe
  allow="camera;microphone"
  src="https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/gum/">
</iframe>
```

[This doesn't work](https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/7r2uzhjf/):

```
<iframe src="https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/gum/">
</iframe>
```

...and in addition to failing with `NotAllowedError`, Safari warns in web console:

```
The top-level frame has prevented a document with a different security origin to
call getUserMedia.
```

This is also a recent update to [the spec](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/getusermedia.html#feature-policy-integration).

Comment: This does not work for me on iOS 12 Safari, even with https and with the iframe snippet. In fact, hitting that link directly doesn't even work: https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/gum/

In both cases, the error is: `NotAllowedError: The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.`

Comment: https was my issue. Thanks!

Comment: Although I get the security implications behind this, it sucks for developing/testing on localhost or a local Intranet IP address. It would be so nice if there was a dev flag to enable this.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out my particular issue was a bug in 12.01. Every device with that version had the issue, and as soon as I updated them to a newer version it went away.